# react-router : how can I change the URL to a "pretty" one once I get my post data loaded?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route like this one

```
<Route
path="/post/:post_id"
exact
component={PostPage}
/>
```

Which loads my `<PostPage/>` component.

In that component, I load my post data (including its name) using the `post_id` parameter.

Once the data is successfully loaded based on that `post_id`; I would like to use the name of that post to make the browser URL prettier.

Example:

- /post/123* : goes to my `<PostPage/>` component
- which loads the post datas for post ID 123; including its name: `post-foo-bar`
- I would like the browser URL to change to */post/123/post-foo-bar*

I guess that using a wrong name should redirect to the good one :

*/post/123/post-not-so-foo-bar* would redirect to */post/123/post-foo-bar*

How could I achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using react-router v6 (it'd be easier/different in v5)

I went through the [base tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route) for react-router, so it's a pretty basic app example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ylwf81?file=src%2Froutes%2Finvoice.jsx

Resulting webpage: https://github-ylwf81--3000.local.webcontainer.io/invoices/1995/Santa%20Monica

The main things to note in this, are the route definitions

For the invoices which would be analogous to your posts:

```
        <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />}>
          <Route
            index
            element={
              <main style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
                <p>Select an invoice</p>
              </main>
            }
          />
          <Route path=":invoiceId">
            <Route index element={<Invoice />} />
            <Route path=":invoiceName" index element={<Invoice />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
```

Note the use of an index route for just the invoiceId, and a separate route for invoiceId + invoiceName.

Because they are both output to the same element, they aren't treated as different by React, so it retains state properly. You can see that in the example by the fact that it doesn't go back to the loading state.

As for the navigation to add in the `invoiceName` to the URL, it's just a basic navigation in a `useEffect` when the name of your object is defined (after an async call). And because this always triggers when the invoice.name changes, and how we aren't actually using the `:invoiceName` variable, it doesn't matter at all what the user inputs for that as long as the `:invoiceId` is correct

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!invoice?.name) {
      return;
    }
    navigate(`/invoices/${invoice.number}/${invoice.name}`);
  }, [invoice?.name, invoice?.number]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` v5 you can declare an array of matching paths to render a routed component on. I suggest adding a matching path that includes a route param for the pretty name.

Example:

```
<Route
  path={["/post/:post_id/:postName", "/post/:post_id"]}
  component={PostPage}
/>
```

Then use an `useEffect` hook on the `PostPage component to check the following cases:

1. If `post_id` param and post id mismatch, then fetch post by id, then redirect to path with post name.
2. If `postName` param, current fetched `post`, and pretty name
   mismatch, then redirect to current path with correct post name.
3. If no `postName` param, current fetched `post`, then redirect to path with post name.

Code

```
const { params, path } = props.match;
const { post_id, postName } = params;

const [post, setPost] = useState();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPost = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const post = await fetchPostById(post_id);
      setPost(post);
      history.replace(
        generatePath(`${path}/:postName`, {
          post_id: post.id,
          postName: post.name
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  if (post_id && post_id !== post?.id) {
    fetchPost();
  } else if (postName && postName !== post?.name) {
    history.replace(
      generatePath(path, {
        post_id: post.id,
        postName: post.name
      })
    );
  } else if (!postName && post?.name) {
    history.replace(
      generatePath(`${path}/:postName`, {
        post_id: post.id,
        postName: post.name
      })
    );
  }
}, [history, post, post_id, postName, path]);
```

[image: Edit react-router-how-can-i-change-the-url-to-a-pretty-one-once-i-get-my-post-dat]